# elements on an html page changing positions on change of resolution

Tags: html, css

```css
    .screen {
      z-index: 100000;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #333;
      width: 1840px;
      height: 1090px;
      top: 400px;
      left: 965px;
      outline: 1px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
      transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
      -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.9828571428571429, 0, 0, -0.00003284072249589491, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) transform: matrix3d(0.9828571428571429, 0, 0, -0.00003284072249589491, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    }
```

```html
<div class="screen">
  <ul id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
    <li class="slideshow__item">
      <img src="img/large/2.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="slideshow__item">
      <img src="img/large/3.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="slideshow__item">
      <img src="img/large/4.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="slideshow__item">
      <img src="img/large/1.png" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<center>
  <img class="tv" src="360.png" style="position:fixed;left: 935px;top:0px;
     z-index: -99;" width="50%" height="90%">
```

i'm trying to get the screen on the tv but it wont stay as the resolution changes 
both the divs translate as we zoom in zoom out

Comment: try using `percentages` instead of set `pixels` units in your design. (change `width and height to 100%`, for example). Or if need be, you can use `calc(100% - 500px);`

Comment: as a side note `<center>` is deprecated and it won't affect anyway a `fixed` element

Comment: thankyou :) jbutler483 and   Fabrizio Calderan

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan i used center in desperation trying to solve the issue :) thankyou soo much for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question would really benefit from a jsfiddle link, since what you've posted is not detailed enough information to create a reproducible example, but I think I understand the central issue. You want a `.screen` div to seemingly be positioned consistently inside a `.tv` element, correct? I think you may be approaching this problem from the wrong angle.

Instead of making `.tv` and `.screen` siblings, you might want to make a container element for both. Then you can absolutely position the screen with % dimensions relative to the TV.

**See for yourself with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9rkhLLz/).**

HTML:

```
<div class="tv-container">
    <img class="tv" src="http://i.imgur.com/PB2GB1q.png">
    <div class="screen">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tv-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.tv {
    width: 100%;
}

.screen {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2.5%;
    top: 3%;
    width: 95%;
    height: 70%;
    background: green;
}
```

Also, don't use `<center>`. Like, ever. The jsfiddle should give you a better way of horizontal/vertical centering.